# Kubernetes + Spring admin UI + Eureka not working

Tags: kubernetes, spring-boot-admin

1. Using Spring Admin + Eureka to monitor all micro-service and deploy it in Kubernetes;
2. Spring Admin UI and discover all micro-service instances, but can't check detail of each instance, check detail network, we can see the 
   service health check has show 502 error:
   http://[admin server real ip]/instances/3f5afb61f59b/actuator/health  >>  502 bad getway
3. Check Eureka register, I found all eureka client was resisted with Kubernetes virtual ip;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolve it, but change the dependency from spring-boot-admin to spring-cloud-admin